# How to create and run a Dart project on the command line

Tags: dart

I wanted to create a Dart project to play around with, but I couldn't figure out how to create one from the command line.

I tried

```
dart create playground.dart
```

I also tried

```
dart playground.dart
```

but the code I pasted in had dependency requirements.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Update

Dart now supports creating projects directly. No more need for stagehand.

```
dart create playground
```

This creates a folder named `playground` with a Dart project inside.

## Alternate answer

#### 1. Create a new folder

```
mkdir playground
```

#### 2. Add a dart file with a main() function

*playground.dart*

```
void main() {
  print("hello world");
}
```

#### 3. Run the app

```
dart playground.dart
```

## If your app has dependencies...

#### 4. Setup configuration

Create a pubspec.yaml file

```
touch pubspec.yaml
```

Paste in any dependencies that you have

```
name: playground
description: Just a place to practice
version: 0.0.1

dependencies:
  crypto: ^2.0.6
```

#### 5. Get dependencies

```
pub get
```

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way to create a new project is to use [Stagehand](https://github.com/dart-lang/stagehand). This is the same that IntelliJ uses when creating a new Dart project.

You can install it with this command

```
pub global activate stagehand
```

And then all you have to do to use it is

```
mkdir playground
cd playground
stagehand <generator-name>
```

These are the different generator you can use right now:

- console-full   - A command-line application sample.
- package-simple - A starting point for Dart libraries or applications.
- server-shelf   - A web server built using the shelf package.
- web-angular    - A web app with material design components.
- web-simple     - A web app that uses only core Dart libraries.
- web-stagexl    - A starting point for 2D animation and games.